# Memory Allocation with "calloc" Fails

Tags: c

I am trying to allocate memory using `calloc` function but when the array size (type `double`) is 48,000 x 48,000 it returns NULL pointer. However, it works perfectly for another case which is 23,000 x 23,000. Technically there should be no problem because I have more than enough RAM on this computer. I am also using the 64bit libraries.

OS: Linux 64bit

Installed memory: 376GB

Compiler: Intel MKL 2019

Compiler link line:

```
icc Main.c -qopenmp -DMKL_ILP64 -m64 -I$MKLROOT/include \
    -L$MKLROOT/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_intel_thread \
    -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl -O2 -o main.out
```

And here the piece of code that I use:

```
int Jsize = 48000;
double *J = NULL;
J = (double *)calloc(Jsize*Jsize, sizeof(double));
if (J == NULL) printf("Null\n");
```

Comment: Somehow, I don't think `calloc` allows you to allocate 18.432 gigabytes of memory.

Comment: @JL2210 I am using 'calloc'. Any alternative?

Comment: @Ash Are you sure you are allowed to allocate that much RAM? There can be a limit on how much you are allowed to allocate on this machine.

Comment: @StaceyGirl yes, I am allowed to use as much as memory that I want.

Comment: @DanD.: That's probably the first value that gives a negative value for `Jsize*Jsize`. See my answer.

Comment: @DanD.I have an idea but I am not sure how it is related to this problem! Maximum range of an integer variable in C is 2,147,483,647, while 46,341^2 = 2,147,488,281 which is greater than this limit....

Comment: @Ash You can use `strace` to check what happens with your program under the hood. In this case you should see a failing `mmap` call with a huge `len` value.

Comment: @ash : In the ILP64 data model, `int` is 64bit.  However, to be sure you would be safer and more correct to use `size_t` since that is the data type for `calloc()` arguments and is 64 bit even in the standard LP64 model used by Linux.

Comment: Are you expecting `-DMKL_ILP64` to tell the compiler to make `int` 64 bits? It almost certainly won't; it just defines a preprocessor macro that presumably affects the behavior of some of the headers you're including. I don't know if icc even has a way to force 64-bit `int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an `int` object named `Jsize`, initialized to 48000. You then compute `Jsize*Jsize`. The mathematical value of that expression is `2304000000`, which exceeds 2<sup>31</sup>-1.

Type `int` on your system is almost certainly 32 bits, which means the multiplication will overflow. The behavior is undefined, but most likely you'll get a negative result.

Remember that the type of an expression in C is determined by the expression itself, not by the context in which it's evaluated. Multiplying an `int` by an `int` always yields an `int` result, even if that result is assigned to something bigger.

That value is then passed as the first argument to `calloc()`, which expects an argument of type `size_t`. If `size_t` is 64 bits (which it probably is), then you're passing a *huge* positive value, probably `18446744071718584320` if my calculations are correct.

On my 64-bit Ubuntu system, when I add a couple of `printf` calls to your code, I get:

```
Jsize*Jsize = -1990967296
(size_t)(Jsize*Jsize) = 18446744071718584320
Null
```

You don't have that much memory.

If you define `Jsize` with type `size_t`, you can at least *try* to allocate the 17+ GiB that you want. (On my system, `calloc` fails with `ENOMEM`, but I don't have as much RAM as you do.)

Note, however, that the OS might not let you allocate that much memory for one process.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Another solution that worked for me was using `unsigned long int` instead. But I still need to test and make sure that the allocated memory is not corrupt.

Comment: @Ash : you should use `size_t` for type agreement with `calloc()`.  I am however surprised - it seems that despite the ILP64 options, the LP64 data model is in use.  Perhaps that is a different question.

Comment: @Ash I think you're linking with ILP64 libraries, but using the LP64 ABI (which is the default on Linux x86_64).

Comment: @Ash: Why would you use `unsigned long int`? Just use `size_t`. That's what `calloc` expects, and you don't have to worry about the possibility that `size_t` might be wider than `unsigned long int` (as it actually is on some systems).